# Как сделать так, чтобы в рабочей директории проекта Python все папки внутри неё так же входили в область директории?

Tags: python, directory

Если файл с данными лежит в той же папке, что и файл питона, то я могу открыть его без указания путей, но если файлы лежат в подпапках, то выдаёт ошибку FileNotFoundError

Comment: надо просто в пути указать и подпапки тоже

Comment: Так вопрос в том, как не указывать пути. Если файл text находится на одном уровне с файлом питона, то чтобы открыть его достаточно open ('text.txt'). Но если text переместить в подпапку, тогда нужно указывать полные пути, чего я и хочу избежать

Comment: Никак. Названия папок такая же часть имени файла, как и само имя. Что делать, если в разных подпапках будут файлы с одинаковыми названиями? Можно, конечно, написать собственную функцию, которая рекурсивно обходить все подпапки и открывает первый найденый файл с указанным именем.

Comment: Спасибо, что просветили. Я ведь считал, что питон действует как раз по описанному вами алгоритму.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы использовать файлы из директорий, который находятся внутри вашей, можно не указывать весь путь целиком, а только последнюю папку. Например, если проект находится в папке dir1, то вместо

```
with open('C:/Users/user/dir1/dir2/file.txt') as file:
    print(file.read())
```

Можно писать

```
with open('dir2/file.txt') as file:
    print(file.read())
```